# Prehash a struct

Tags: rust, hash, hashmap

I have struct with many fields that I want to use as a key in a HashMap.

I often need to use the struct multiple times to access different HashMaps and I don't want to compute the hash and possible clone each time as the program needs to be as performant as possible and it will be accessing the HashMaps a lot (billions of times so the time really stacks up).

Here is a simplified example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Clone)]
struct KeyStruct {
  field1: usize,
  field2: bool,
}

fn main() {
    // This is what I'm doing now
    let key = KeyStruct { field1: 1, field2: true };

    // This is what I'd like to do
    // let key = key.get_hash() 

    let mut map1 = HashMap::new();
    let mut map2 = HashMap::new();
    let mut map3 = HashMap::new();
    let mut map4 = HashMap::new();

    if !map1.contains_key(&key) {
        map1.insert(key.clone(), 1);
    }
    
    if !map2.contains_key(&key) {
        map2.insert(key.clone(), 2);
    }

    if !map3.contains_key(&key) {
        map3.insert(key.clone(), 3);
    }

    if !map4.contains_key(&key) {
        map4.insert(key.clone(), 4);
    }
}
```

I never actually use the values in the `KeyStruct`, I just want to use it as a key to the HashMaps. I would like to avoid hashing it multiple times and cloning it like is done in that example.

Comment: Do you have a measurable performance problem or are you just concerned about performance in general? I think you're going *deep* down the path of premature optimization as the hash calculation here should be inconsequential. Even on hashes with literal billions of items the cost is marginal. Remember, if you're not happy with the default `Hash` implementation you can always write your own, and that one could be cached, but I'd suggest this is an extraordinarily bad idea to implement until you have a severe performance problem that cannot be tackled any other way.

Comment: You probably want to use something like the [`raw_entry_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut) API. It's experimental in the standard library, but it's available [in the `hashbrown` crate](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut)

Comment: @tadman I know the hashing isn't that big of a concern, I'm more worried about the cloning of the big struct that is required (it has 11 fields at the moment with vecs etc.). If I could prehash the struct, then this wouldn't be a problem, because cloning the hash would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: I'd go with the simplest thing that can possibly work first, then if you're having performance problems start digging into flamegraph performance data to see where the issues lie. If you're cloning the hash frequently, maybe you need to [have a `Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), or perhaps pick another data structure that maps better to your access patterns.

Comment: @tadman The Hashmaps will be read from billions of times so the milliseconds really start to stack up. Also that Cow seems interesting, I'll have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: There's a cost to hashing both for insertion *and* reading, so if your hashing function is being hit really hard, it is possible to bake in a pre-computed hash value into anything you're looking up, though you'll want to be sure these values get used repeatedly so you're not just wasting space with values used once.

Comment: It's also worth keeping in mind the bigger picture as the real cost of `HashMap` is not the hashing function itself, but the way the allocations are spread out all over your address space, making caching really painful for the CPU. If you can use a structure that's equivalent to a `Vec` with contiguous data, you can often get substantially improved performance. If your data changes infrequently, a simple priority list with a binary search can perform fantastically well in practice.

Comment: Yes I meant accessed billions of times, i.e. reads/writes. Also vectors are not an option here since there are billions of keys and we need fast reads and writes.